# Term for an A*-like pathfinding strategy where only the heuristic goal distance matters

Tags: terminology, shortest-path, graph-traversal, heuristics, a-star-search

I am trying to find a proper term for the [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)-like best-first pathfinding strategy where the node to expand next is the one with the least estimated distance from the goal, regardless of its distance from the source.

In *best-first* search algorithms, the node to expand next is the most promising one according to some evaluation function (which may take into account the current global knowledge).  In the normal A* algorithm, the evaluation function is the sum of the length of the currently know shortest path from the source and the heuristic estimate of the distance to the goal.  Is there a standard term for a similar strategy where the evaluation function is just the heuristic distance to the goal?

I was thinking about *greedy* and *hill-climbing*, but *greedy* in this context seems to be just a synonym of *best-first*, and in what is commonly referred to as *hill-climbing*, there seems to be either no backtracking, or just one-step backtracking, that is, old unexpanded nodes are discarded at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [greedy best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search#Greedy_BFS).

Comment: Indeed, it is so called in *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* by Russell and Norvig, though this does not look appropriate. (Any "best-first" is greedy by definition, i think.)

Comment: @Alexey I completely agree!

Comment: I would have called it something like *impatient best-first*.